# Getting error when trying to destruct my linked - list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Im trying to implement a destructor for the objects of linked-list Iv created.  I made a function called MakeEmpty, that I simply called inside the destructor.  It compiled correctly the first time, but now, I am getting instant crashes with an error saying:

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong? I ran the debugger and pointed out where it says the error is in the code, but I cant figure out whats wrong.

```
WORD::~WORD()
{
cout << "Destructor Called"<<endl;

(*this).MakeEmpty();
}
```

And this is the MakeEmpty() function

```
void WORD::MakeEmpty()
{
alpha_numeric *p = (*this).front;

if((*this).IsEmpty())
{
    cout <<"Already empty"<< endl;
    return;
}

while(front != 0)
{
    front = front -> next;
    delete p;//<<<<---DEBUGGER SAYS ERROR HERE
    p = front;
}
return;
}
```

Comment: Did you obey the rule of three in your class? The error sounds like you are missing a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator.

Comment: @FlorianSowade  ohh yeaa, thats it, put that as an answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you obey the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) in your class? The error sounds like you are missing a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator.